# If any object is rotated, does it rotate with same angle with respect to any point on the object?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, rotations, plane-geometry

Consider a 2D shape.
If it is rotated around any point $P$ on it, then $P$ is kept fixed.

Let there be another point $Q$ on it.
And compare the final position and initial axes  at point $Q$.

Will the rotation with respect to $Q$ be the same as $P$?

Comment: I am not sure If I understand what you write, but perhaps you want this: A shape rotated around $p$ by angle $\alpha$ and the same shape  rotated around $q$ by the same angle $\alpha$  differ only by a translation.

Comment: Exactly I meant this. Is there a proof for that? I tried to drawing cordinate axes and parallel lines theorem.